# How jdbc return autogenerate key- internal working

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, id);

        preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
        primaryKeyResultset= preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(primaryKeyResultset.next()){
            generatedId= primaryKeyResultset.getLong(1);
        }
```

how return autogenerated key works internally ? does it lock that row to get key ?

Comment: I get the sense that this is more of a general database question rather than something to do with Java.  Which database are you using?

Comment: mysql ,but my question is how jdbc internally returning the key when there is no unique value in row except auto generated primary key ? like it's locking that perticuler row and unlocking when retuning ?

Comment: JDBC is an API and set of requirements, how it works (and if it follows the JDBC requirements) depends on the implementation. If you want to know what the MySQL driver does, look at their source. In any case, you should never just assume that the first column of a generated keys result set is 1) generated and 2) the primary key.

Comment: ok so can you tell me how it will for mysql, in my table i have only one auto generated primary key so i put get(1)